# How to drop a column of datatype datetime?

Tags: python, pandas

[image: datatype]

I want to drop the `Admission time` and `Discharge time` columns but I am not able to drop them by using this code:

```
df.drop(columns=["Admission time "],inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the axis;

- `axis = 0`: row wise
- `axis = 1`: column wise

In your case;

```
# make sure the column names match
df.drop(['column_A', 'column_B'], axis = 1, inplace=True)

# also, you can drop them by number
df = df.drop(df.columns[[0, 1]], axis=1, inplace=True)
```